# Date column in mysql table not being updated

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have the following table that I am updating from a ruby script, alough the fact that is it a ruby script I do not think is relevant unless it is to do with a bug in the mysql gem (which seems unlikely).

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| venue_code    | varchar(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| title         | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description   | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start_date    | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_time    | time          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_modified | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_created  | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| url           | varchar(500)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price         | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| url_ticket    | varchar(500)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am running the following SQL using the mysql.query method (again, I think its a SQL problem but just in case its a ruby thing).

```
INSERT INTO events 
  ( venue_code, start_date, start_time, title, price, url, url_ticket,
    description, date_created) 
VALUES( 
  'OLDDUKEBRI', 
  IF('2017-08-30'='',NULL,'2017-08-30'), 
  IF(''='',NULL,''), 
  IF('Swampcandy'='',NULL,'Swampcandy'), 
  IF(''='',NULL,''), 
  '', 
  IF(''='',NULL,''), 
  IF(''='',NULL,''), 
  NOW() 
)
```

And the date is not being updated to '2017-08-30', it is being updated to '0000-00-00'.

In terms of versions mysql is 'mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2' and ruby is 'ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]'

All help on this one would be regretfully appreciated.
Ben

Comment: `IF('2017-08-30'='',NULL,'2017-08-30')` ... what is the intended meaning of this, because I don't think it is doing what you want.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35939/1.

Comment: Yes, verry odd, I was working on the surounding code and the problem went awway.  FYI The ruby code generating this was "'IF('#{date}'='',NULL,'#{date}')'.  Its basicaly so varables with '' gets mapped to NULL.  Its the kind of thing I used to do years ago when working with OracleRDMS.